# phonegap map app working on (browser) laptop but not working on Android phone

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Good day good people, I'm having a good problem I developed an Mobile App using phonegap to get my current location. It worked perfectly on my laptop browser but refuses to work on my android device. Please I need your assistance. Below are the code I used.Thanks

Javascript File

```
// JavaScript Document
// When map page is shown, run function
$('#gmap').live("pagecreate", function() {
    // Create gmap object, centering on given latitude/longitude, with a terrain map type
    $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': '6.45306, 3.39583', 'mapTypeId': 'terrain'}).bind('init', function(evt, map) {
        // Use geolocation function watchPosition() to get position and success/fail status
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('watchPosition', function(position, status) {
            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                // Set variable 'latlng' to values from watchPosition() function arg 'position'
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                // Set up marker
                var markers = $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'markers' );
                if ( !markers['client'] ) {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'id': 'client', 'position': latlng, 'bounds': true });
                } else {
                    markers['client'].setPosition(latlng);
                    map.panTo(latlng);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Config.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.ahyoxsoft.eNigeria"
    version   = "1.0.0">

<name>XXXXXX</name>

<description>xxxxxx</description>

<author href="https://xxxxx.com" email="info@xxxxx.com">
Your Name
</author>

<icon src="images/icon/android/ic_ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="images/icon/android/ic_mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="images/icon/android/ic_hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="images/icon/android/ic_xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

<icon src="images/icon/bb/ic.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
<icon src="images/icon/bb/ic_hover.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>

<icon src="images/icon/webos/ic.png" gap:platform="webos" />
<icon src="images/icon/webos/miniicon.png" gap:platform="webos" gap:role="mini" />

<icon src="images/icon/winphone/ic.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="images/icon/winphone/tileicon.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" />


</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
```